# Generar una lista con una secuencia

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quiero hacer una lista para emplear como nombre de Filas de un Dataframe. Por lo que necesito generar una extensa lista con un termino común pero variando un caracter.

```
Lista = ["Dia 1", "Dia 2", "Dia 3", "Dia 4", ...]
```

Y generar tantos elemento como yo defina. Solo hay que repetir en este caso la palabra "Dia" y sumarle "1" al número que lo acompaña.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow! ¿Que has intentado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías hacer algo como esto para generar la lista:

```
cantidad = 100
lista = [f'Dia {x+1}' for x in range(cantidad)]
```

De esta manera estarías creando la lista, según la cantidad que necesitas. 
Espero haberte ayudado

Comment: Muchas gracias, es exactamente lo que buscaba